# Porque essa função não esta retornando nada?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estou tentando implementar lista duplamente linkada e tem sido um desastre. A seguinte função (display()) deveria retornar os dados da struct, mas não retorna nada. Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pessoa
{
    int id;
    int idade;
    char nome[45];
    struct pessoa *prox;
    struct pessoa *ante;
} * head;

void add_to_list(struct pessoa *ptr, int pessoa_id, int pessoa_idade, char nome[])
{
    int flag = 0;
    struct pessoa *temp = head;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct pessoa));
    ptr->id = pessoa_id;
    ptr->idade = pessoa_idade;
    strcpy(ptr->nome, nome);
    ptr->prox = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = ptr;
        printf("Dados adicionado com sucesso.\n");
        printf("-----------------------------\n");
        return;
    }

    int result1 = strcasecmp(head->nome, ptr->nome);
    if(result1 >= 0) {
            ptr->prox = head;
            head->ante = ptr;
            head = ptr;
            printf("Dados adicionado com sucesso.\n");
            printf("--------------------------\n");
            return;
        }
    
    if (head->prox != NULL)
    {
        temp = head->prox;
        while (temp->prox != NULL)
        {
            int result = strcasecmp(temp->nome, ptr->nome);
            if (result >= 0)
            {
                struct pessoa *temp_prev = temp->ante;
                ptr->prox = temp;
                temp_prev->prox = ptr;
                ptr->ante = temp_prev;
                temp->ante = ptr;
                flag = 1;
                return;
            }
            temp = temp->prox;
        }
        int result2 = strcasecmp(temp->nome, ptr->nome);
        if (result2 >= 0)
        {
            struct pessoa *temp_prev1 = temp->ante;
            ptr->prox = temp;
            temp_prev1->prox = ptr;
            ptr->ante = temp_prev1;
            temp->ante = ptr;
            flag = 1;
            return;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0)
    {
        temp->prox = ptr;
        ptr->ante = temp;
    }
    printf("Dado adicionado com sucesso.\n");
    printf("----------------------------\n");
}

void display(struct pessoa *ptr)
{
    struct pessoa *temp = head;
    if (temp = NULL)
    {
        printf("Ops, vazio.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("Name: %s\nID: %d\nIdade: %d\n\n\n ", temp->nome, temp->id, temp->idade);
            temp = temp->prox;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct pessoa s;
    struct pessoa *p = &s;
    int recebe_id = 1;
    int recebe_idade = 25;
    char recebe_nome[45] = "leonardo";

    add_to_list(p, recebe_id, recebe_idade, recebe_nome);
    display(p);
}
```

O programa no main() é puramente pra testes. Já quebrei tanto a cabeça que nem sei mais o que eu to fazendo, socorro

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Você está passando um ponteiro (endereço para uma variável) para a tua função, e dentro desta função, alocando memória para uma estrutura, substituindo o endereço apontado pelo ponteiro e trabalhando em cima desse espaço novo alocado. Comente a linha do malloc e teste novamente.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não funcionou mas o problema pode ser isso mesmo. To perdido

Comment: Epa, agora que eu vi. Na tua checagem "if (temp = NULL)" o certo é "if(temp == NULL)"

Comment: Perfeito, cara. Funcionou que é uma beleza. Muitíssimo grato, salvou meu dia 